# MySQL Query with join and Alias without table name

Tags: mysql, select, alias

i encountered a funny problem:

I have two table t1 and t2 with several columns. Because two columns in the both tables have the same name, i need to to this:

```
SELECT t1.foo AS ID, t2.bar as NAME
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.foo = t2.foo;
```

The Answers are headed with t1.ID, t2.NAME

I don´t wont the table names in the headlines.

Funny thing: Using the same query in a view returns the correct / wanted headings: ID...NAME

I want to use those queries in stored procedures where the same behaviour has been observed.

Tried with MySQL 5.5.9

Any idea how to avoid the table names in the headlines?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM (SELECT t1.foo AS ID, t2.bar as NAME
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.foo = t2.foo) AS t;
```

Comment: Hi, found this meanwhile out for myself but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the linked tablename from a field with a simple string or int function:

```
SELECT (t1.foo+0) AS ID, CONCAT(t2.bar) as NAME
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.foo = t2.foo;
```